# How to create a new screen from the main screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, screen, android-button

I want to create a new screen, when I click on *"Report"* `Button`. And on that new screen, I want to display the list of items.
I tried it,but failed. I created a new `Activity` class, and a new `xml` file.

public class Report extends MainActivity {

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.report);

    ListView mWeek = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.week); 
    ListView mMonth = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.month); 
    ListView mYear = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.year); 
}
```

In `MainActivity.java`:

```
public void createReport(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Report.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Is there any other way to create new `screen`, plz give any other way to create it.

Comment: How you failed. What is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create new menuclass.xml for what you want to display..... 
give id on them.

```
View v1= findViewById(R.id.subid);
b1= (Button)v1;

b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Intent intent=new Intent(Main.this,MenuCalls.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

and create new MenuCalls class in write

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menucalls);

    ListView mWeek = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.week); 
    ListView mMonth = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.month); 
    ListView mYear = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.year); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use fragments.every fragment  has a view,with fragment transaction you can manage multiple view in an single activity.